# How do I determine the purpose of this op-amp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, inverting-amplifier, non-inverting

I have this circuit and I was asked to determine V2=f(V1) and V3=f(V2) which I determined below. The next step is to figure out what the purpose of this circuit is but I'm not sure how to do it from the equations I got.

[image: circuit]

Answer (score 3):

The first op-amp is a differential amplifier set up to measure its common mode rejection ratio, and possibly its common mode input range.

The second op-amp is an inverting, dampened low pass filter. Real-world application is not known but possibly used to dampen a peak in the frequency response of the first op-amp.

Comment: How did you arrive at that conclusion

Comment: Is it not obvious? I have see hundreds of these over the last 40 years.

Comment: It is not obvious for me

Comment: Then you need to study more op-amps wired with differential inputs that are shorted together to perform common mode testing.

Comment: For this purpose R1=R2 and R3=R4.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see what the first half of the circuit does. It could be a differential amplifier with the inputs tied together, depending on the res values. The second half is an inverting amplifier, as your equations show, with a pole at some frequency determined by C and R7 and a zero at a higher frequency determined by R6, R7 and C. So some sort of equaliser?